# How to build DBD::mysql with DBI in a custom @INC?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dbd, makemaker

I'm building DBI and DBD::mysql in a continuous integration build server. The build of DBI is successful, as seen in the excerpt of the build log below. It clearly installs DBI/DBD.pm in the correct location.

```
pushd DBI-1.643

perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/data/pods/mysql-tools/mysql-tools/current

...
Installing /data/pods/mysql-tools/mysql-tools/current/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBI/DBD.pm
...
Appending installation info to /data/pods/mysql-tools/mysql-tools/current/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
```

But the next part of the build for DBD::mysql fails because it can't find the files installed by DBI.

```
pushd DBD-mysql-4.050

perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/data/pods/mysql-tools/mysql-tools/current --ssl

Can't locate DBI/DBD.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5 
/usr/share/perl5 .) 
at Makefile.PL line 15.
```

You can see, MakeMaker for DBD::mysql isn't adding the install location to its `@INC` at all. It just has default directories.

Is there a way to pass an argument to MakeMaker to add the install directory to `@INC`? I suppose I could hard-code it, but that seems improper and hard to maintain. Is there a better way to automatically add `INSTALL_BASE/lib/perl5/<arch>` to `@INC`?

Environment:

- CentOS 7 Linux
- Perl 5.16.3

I would have preferred to use cpanm of course. But the CI build server is isolated from the internet because of my employer's security policy. No http proxying is allowed from CI.

Comment: read "perldoc perlrun", pass additional directory with -I switch (capital "i")

Comment: Try set your `PERL5LIB` environment variable before running `perl Makefile.PL`, for example in your `~/.bashrc` init file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#INSTALL_BASE), `INSTALL_BASE` is used for telling `make install` where to put the installed module:

> INSTALL_BASE
>
> `INSTALL_BASE` can be passed into `Makefile.PL` to change where your
> module will be installed. `INSTALL_BASE` is more like what everyone else
> calls "prefix" than `PREFIX` is.

but it does not tell `perl` where to look for installed modules. To do that you can use the environment variable `PERL5LIB`, according to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun) :

> PERL5LIB
>
> A list of directories in which to look for Perl library files before
> looking in the standard library. Any architecture-specific and
> version-specific directories, such as `version/archname/`, `version/`, or
> `archname/` under the specified locations are automatically included if
> they exist, with this lookup done at interpreter startup time. In
> addition, any directories matching the entries in
> `$Config{inc_version_list}` are added.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work by running `PERL5LIB=/data/pods/mysql-tools/mysql-tools/current/lib/perl5 perl Makefile.PL ...`